# Pyrogram does not work inside the Pytelegrambotapi Handler

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telegram-api, pyrogram

There is a handler for processing messages for the telegram bot. Inside under certain conditions, the Pyrogram method should operate

```
# coding: utf8
import telebot
from pyrogram import *
import time
bot   = telebot.TeleBot('BOTTOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def mes_handler(message):
    if message.text == 'Test123':
        app = Client('my_account')
        print(1)
        with app:
            print(2)
            users_data = app.iter_chat_members(groupID)
            print(users_data)

while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(15)
```

before `with app:` everything works, after no. (outputs only 1, 2 no, it means mistake in `with app:`. If i use `with app:` outside of handler everything works

Answer (score 0):

Using synchronous functions to connect to pytelegrambotapi, and then using asynchronous execution of pyrogram will solve this problem

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Test123")
def pyrogram_worker(message):
    message_chat_id = message.chat.id

    async def notify_all():
        async with Client(config.bot_name, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=config.botapi) as app:
            ret = ""
            async for member in app.get_chat_members(message_chat_id):
                if member.user.username:
                    ret += f"@{member.user.username} "
            await app.send_message(message_chat_id, ret)

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)


    loop.run_until_complete(notify_all())
```